# Javascript: Fetch data while executing code

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am building an app that relies on some data I need to fetch from my server. Right now my app starts with fetching the data and then passing down the data through several steps which are separated by classes. I simplify the code in the following.

Class1:

```js
export default class Class1 {

    constructor(props) {
        this.props = props
    }
    
    async init() {
        const data = await this.fetchData()
        new Screen({ data }).init()
    }
    
    async fetchData() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
            xhr.open("POST", 'http://localhost:8888/getData', true)
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            xhr.onload = () => resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText))
            xhr.onerror = reject
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({}))
        })
    }

}
```

Class2:

```js
export default class Screen {

    constructor(props) {
        this.props = props
    }
    
    async init() {
        let ScreenType
        if (this.offscreenIsSupported()) ScreenType = Offscreen
        else ScreenType = Onscreen

        new ScreenType(this.props).init()
    }

    offscreenIsSupported() {
        return "OffscreenCanvas" in window && "transferControlToOffscreen" in this.props.canvas
    }

}
```

OnscreenClass:

```js
export default class Onscreen {

    constructor(props) {
        this.props = props
    }
    
    async init() {
        new Handler(this.props}).init()
    }

}
```

OffscreenClass:

```js
export default class Offscreen {

    constructor(props) {
        this.props = props
    }
    
    async init() {
        this.worker = new Worker(new URL('./offscreen.worker.js', import.meta.url))
        const offscreen = this.props.canvas.transferControlToOffscreen()
        this.worker.postMessage({
            type: "init",
            canvas: offscreen
        }, [offscreen])
    }
}
```

offscreen.worker.js

```js
self.onmessage = msg => {
    switch (msg.data.type) {
      case 'init':
        init(msg.data)
        break
    }
}

async function init(data) {
  self.vgHandler = new Handler({ data })
  await self.vgHandler.init()
}
```

Class3:

```js
export default class Handler {

    constructor(props) {
        this.props = props
    }

    async init() {
        this.setup(this.props.data)
    }
    
}
```

As you can see the main code called in Class3 will be the same. This Class needs the fetched data. Class2 is just necessary to determine if the browser should use offscreen or onscreen canvas. Since checking the ability of using offscreen canvas as well as creating the web worker is not dependent to the fetched data it is not very smart to await the fetching process.

How am I able to fetch the data in background, run my code of Class2 simultaneously and use the fetched data in Class3?

I want to make this process as fast as possible.

Best

Comment: Could you provide a bit more of your code?

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: Are you using react (given the usage of `props`)?

Comment: I am just using webpack without react. I use the props due to the classes.

Comment: In general, immediately create and initialise your `new Screen` without passing it data, then call a `putData` setter later when it is fetched. Of course that means the screen will have to deal with (not) rendering absent data.

Comment: Your code creates a lot of `new` instances without ever storing the objects anywhere, always calling the `init` method immediately and never reusing them. This suggests you probably shouldn't use `class`es at all, just plain functions that return (a promise for) a result. (If they even have one, as your functions don't have `return` values either)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it better for performance to use functions instead of classes in general? Is there a better approach than nesting the classes? I simplified the code above. I used classes for each level to be able to access the functions and data from Class3 at top level.

Comment: The performance difference would be minuscule, it's rather a readability and simplicity issue. I don't know what simplifications you've made. I recommend classes only for stateful objects with methods called independently. It's not quite clear what you mean by "*access functions and data at the top level*", but a stateless handlers whose job it is to handle a result should be a simple `function` that can be called.